# Quartz document code don't work

Tags: asp.net, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use Quartz document code from [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03) but it Doesn't work. My program don't recognize `simpleSchedule()` in line 10!

```
// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
  .withIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
  .build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
  .withIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
  .startNow()
  .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
      .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
      .repeatForever())            
  .build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: `simpleSchedule()` is calling a method. Have you defined it?

Comment: @OskarKjellin No, I didn't define it! I thought it is a default function in quartz! how should I define it? I mean what should it return and what should I define in it?

Comment: Are you using java or C#? The code you showed is for java, but your tag is for asp.net

Comment: What's the error? Btw simpleSchedule() is built in (org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder). Do you have "using org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*"?

Comment: @Papa Your answer helped me. you can write it as an answer to get the bounty score...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included this?

```
using org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
```

(thanks)

Comment: you wrote it for java? I use asp.net! I just used **Quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder** instead of **simpleSchedule()**

Comment: That is asp.net. If you declare the library at the top of your code, then you don't need to fully type it out. Either way is fine.

Comment: @ ok .. my program don't recognize 'using org.quartz..' so I thought it is java... however thanks for your answer.

Comment: Was getting error for sampleSchedule();  in java.
Fixed this by importing
using org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;

Thanks for the hint!